# android Change background color of odd rows in RecyclerView when using DiffUtil

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have a RecyclerView and Every odd row has a different background color.
I try to add `DiffUtil` to speed up the updates like this:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.asdf.android.R
import com.asdf.android.network.model.trade.MarketTradeItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_trade_history.view.*

class MarketTradesListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: MutableList<MarketTradeItem>,
    val theme: Int
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflate =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_trade_history, parent, false)
        return ItemHolder(inflate)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemHolder = holder as ItemHolder
        itemHolder.bind(list[position], position)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any>
    ) {
        if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        } else {
            val payload = payloads[0] as DiffUtilPayload
            val itemHolder = holder as ItemHolder
            itemHolder.bind(list[position], position, payload)
        }
    }

    fun setList(it: List<MarketTradeItem>) {
        it.forEachIndexed { index, item -> item.position = index }

        DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffCallback(list, it),true).dispatchUpdatesTo(this)

        list.clear()
        list.addAll(it)
    }

    inner class ItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(
            order: MarketTradeItem,
            position: Int,
            payload: DiffUtilPayload = DiffUtilPayload()
        ) {


            var color: Int
            if (theme == R.style.Apptheme) {
                color = R.color.listBackgroundColorLight
            } else {
                color = R.color.listBackgroundColorDark
            }
//            if (payload.isPositionChanged)
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                if (position % 2 == 0) ContextCompat.getColor(
                    itemView.context,
                    android.R.color.transparent
                ) else
                    ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, color)
            )


            itemView.textViewPrice.setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    itemView.context,
                    if (order.isRaise) R.color.buy_green else R.color.sell_red
                )
            )
            if (payload.isPriceChanged) {
                itemView.textViewPrice.text = order.price
            }
            if (payload.isAmountChanged) {
                itemView.textViewAmount.text = order.amount
            }
            if (payload.isTimeChanged) {
                itemView.textViewTime.text = order.time
            }


        }
    }

    class DiffCallback(
        private val oldList: List<MarketTradeItem>,
        private val newList: List<MarketTradeItem>
    ) : DiffUtil.Callback() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
        }

        override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
            return oldList.size
        }

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
            return newList.size
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
        }

        override fun getChangePayload(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Any? {
            val oldItem = oldList[oldItemPosition]
            val newItem = newList[oldItemPosition]
            return DiffUtilPayload(
                oldItem.price != newItem.price,
                oldItem.amount != newItem.amount,
                oldItem.createdAt != newItem.createdAt,
                oldItem.time != newItem.time,
                oldItem.position != newItem.position
            )
        }

    }

    data class DiffUtilPayload(
        val isPriceChanged: Boolean = true,
        val isAmountChanged: Boolean = true,
        val isCreatedAtChanged: Boolean = true,
        val isTimeChanged: Boolean = true,
        val isPositionChanged: Boolean = true
    )

}
```

The problem is that the background color of even and odd rows does not appear correctly when new items are inserted to the list and appears like this:

[image]
The background color is set randomly and not appear as alternate even/odd.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the source for `MarketTradeItem`? I think the problem is that your `areContentsTheSame()` method is returning `true` when it needs to return `false`.

Comment: Hi @BenP. If only one item changes, we need to update all the items to paint the alternate color, How its related with the areContentsTheSame?

Comment: Have you logged the items and booleans your DiffUtil functions are returning to make sure the comparison and output are correct?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change `areContentsTheSame` method in your DiffUtil. If the contents are same, it won't calculate the change which won't dispatch `notifyItemChanged(position)` to the adapter. And it won't call `onBindViewHolder` for that position/item.

You should try changing the method to

```
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition] && oldItemPosition % 2 == newItemPosition % 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if items are added at the beginning. the fast solution would be, in onBindViewHolder

```
itemHolder.bind(list[position], position, payload)
```

change to:

```
itemHolder.bind(list[position], getItemCount() - position, payload)
```

and  `itemHolder.bind(list[position], position)`

change to:

```
itemHolder.bind(list[position], getItemCount() - position)
```

I think the view holder should not know the postion. so I suggest you some refactoring.

Comment: It has been a long time since I am not working on that project anymore but how do you think this will fix it?

Comment: when you change list in adapter, onbind is called only on new elements, becouse of diffutils. so if u had for example 10 element, and add 11 element, on bind is called for just last one, and becouse you are adding new items on top, new element position always will be 0, 0%2 =0 always. so i changed logic, size - position will vary.